For positive $x$, $y$, and $z$ with $x+y+z=3$, find the minimum of $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^3+8}}+\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{y^3+8}}+\frac{z^2}{\sqrt{z^3+8}}$.
This is a slightly modified exercise problem for high-school math contests:

For positive $x$, $y$, and $z$ with $x+y+z=3$, find the minimum of $$\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^3+8}}+\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{y^3+8}}+\frac{z^2}{\sqrt{z^3+8}}.$$

I only managed to find the minimum with a little help of differential calculus:

Let $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^3+8}}$. For $x=y=z=1$, the objective is $f(x)+f(y)+f(z)=1$.
For $x>2$, we have $f(x)>f(2)=1$ since $f(x)$ is increasing. But the objective can achieve $1$ as above. So the objective won't be minimum if any of $x$, $y$, or $z$ is $>2$.
I find the tangent line at $x=1$ for function $f(x)$ to be
$$\ell(x)=\frac{11}{18}x-\frac{5}{18}.$$
I can show that line $\ell(x)$ lies below $f(x)$ for $0<x \leq 2$. This eventually involves studying the shape of a cubic.
For $0<x,y,z \leq 2$, $$f(x)+f(y)+f(z)\geq \ell(x)+\ell(y)+\ell(z) = 1.$$

Note: $f(x)$ is neither concave nor convex over the interval $(0,3)$, and the tangent line intersects with $f(x)$ at some value $x>2$. So restricting attention to $0<x\leq2$ helps to establish the inequality.

My question: How should I  find the minimum by only using inequalities well-known to high school students (with as little calculus as possible)?
Edit: To me, using Lagrange multipliers or KKT conditions seems involving more calculus than the tangent line trick above. So I'm not looking for those solutions.

EDIT: Some of my unsuccessful attempts:

Directly use Cauchy-Scharwz inequality / Titu's lemma on the original objective to obtain
$$\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^3+8}}+\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{y^3+8}}+\frac{z^2}{\sqrt{z^3+8}} \ge
\frac{(x+y+z)^2}{\sqrt{x^3+8}+\sqrt{y^3+8}+\sqrt{z^3+8}}.
$$
The right-hand side is too small.
Rewrite each term in the form $$\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^3+8}}=\frac{6x^3}{2(3x)\sqrt{x^3+8}}$$ and then apply $a^2+b^2\geq2ab$ to the denominator to remove the troublesome square roots:
$$
\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^3+8}}\geq \frac{6x^3}{(3x)^2+(x^3+8)}
$$
Now apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality / Titu's lemma to get
$$\text{objective}\geq \frac{6\left(x^{3/2}+y^{3/2}+z^{3/2}\right)^2}{\left(x^3+y^3+z^3\right)+9\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)+24}.
$$But then I got trouble with the numerator and don't know how to deal with the cross-product terms $(xy)^{3/2}+(yz)^{3/2}+(zx)^{3/2}$.


The tangent line trick is a useful tool in high school contests, I don't know why you don't consider it "well-known" to students. In fact, there are many instances of official solutions to IMO containing alternate solutions employing calculus.

@DS Thanks for the comment. I don't know how much differential calculus is taught in different regions / schools. I thought students might have trouble in finding derivatives involving square roots or involving the chain rule. But it's good know that IMO official solution might occasionally rely on calculus.

You may consider using Hölder: $\sum x^2\left(x^3+8\right)\cdot\left(\sum\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^3+8}}\right)^2\ge\left(\sum x^2\right)^3\ge 1^2\cdot\sum x^2\left(x^3+8\right)$.

@Vic_Dis Thank you so much for the nice idea! Could you please explain more on the 2nd inequality sign?

At this time it is just an idea that seems true. I may make it into an answer when I find some time to try and develop it further.

I, too, find the tangent line argument appealing. Basically because the constraint is on the sum of the variables. Then again, when I was competing there weren't any problems on this type of inequalities, so I am not very good at these :-)

Could you work with Randon's Inequality and reduce it to $f(x,y,z) \ge \frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{\sqrt{x^3+y^3+z^3+24}}$, see if you can could further reduce this

@SatishRamanathan Thanks. But this also overshoots: for $x=y=z=1$, the RHS becomes $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}<1$.

Is the minimum value 1? In other words,, do you know the answer for this

@SatishRamanathan Yes. The minimum is 1, as shown in my proof using the tangent line trick in the question.

@Ryan Shen My Hölder idea leads to a proof that is valid yet technically complicated. Do elementary symmetric polynomials (i.e. $pqr$ method) fall within the scope of high school methods in your country? Is it supposed to be strictly a pen and paper solution?

@Vic_Dis Thanks. Symmetric polynomials are fine and calculators are not allowed.

To prove $$\sum_{x,y,z}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^3+8}}\ge 1$$ for $x,y,z>0$ we can use Hölder. We have $$\sum_{x,y,z} x^2\left(x^3+8\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{x,y,z}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^3+8}}\right)^2\ge\left(\sum_{x,y,z} x^2\right)^3$$ therefore it suffices to prove $$\left(\sum_{x,y,z} x^2\right)^3\ge 1^2\cdot\sum_{x,y,z} x^2\left(x^3+8\right)$$
In terms of $p=x+y+z,\ q=xy+yz+zx,\ r=xyz$ and after homogenization we can write the last inequality as $$\left(p^2-2q\right)^3\ge\left(p^5-5p^3q+5p^2r+5pq^2-5qr\right)\frac{p}{3}+8\left(p^2-2q\right)\frac{p^4}{81}$$ or \begin{gather}135pqr-135p^3r-648q^3+837p^2q^2-335p^4q+46p^6\ge 0\tag{$*$}\end{gather}
Since $p^2>q$ hence the LHS of $(*)$ is decreasing in $r$ and it suffices to check only the case when $r$ attains its largest value possible, i.e. when two of $x,y,z$ are equal. By homogeneity we can take $p=2+x$, $q=1+2x$, $r=x$, where $x>0$, to obtain $$2(x-1)^2\left(16x^4+x^3+7x^2(x-1)^2+83x^2+x+142\right)\ge 0.$$ The factor $(x-1)^2$ is obvious because that is our equality point. The longer one is obtained with long division.

On a side note, $(*)$ can also be written as
\begin{multline*}24\left(p^3-4pq+9r\right)^2+6\left(q^2-3pr\right)p^2+22\left(p^2-3q\right)\left(p^4-5p^2q+6pr+4q^2\right)\\ +128\left(p^2-3q\right)\left(q^2-3pr\right) +33p\left(p^2-3q\right)\left(pq-9r\right)+216(pq-9r)r\ge 0.\end{multline*}

Regarding the OP's doubts.
We do not necessarily need differential calculus to employ the tangent line trick here. All we need to know is that the graph of the objective function kind of bounces off the tangent line at the point of tangency.
First, by AM-GM we have $$\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{t^3+8}}=\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{(t+2)\left(t^2-2t+4\right)}}\ge\frac{2t^2}{(t+2)+\left(t^2-2t+4\right)}=\frac{2t^2}{t^2-t+6}.$$
To find the equation of the tangent line to $\frac{2t^2}{t^2-t+6}$ at $t=1$ consider the equation $$\frac{2t^2}{t^2-t+6}=\frac{1}{3}+m(t-1).$$ It is equivalent to $$(t-1)\left(-3mt^2+(3m+5)t+6(1-3m)\right)=0$$
The bouncing off feature means that the LHS of the last equation must be divisible by $(t-1)^2$, i.e. that $$-3mt^2+(3m+5)t+6(1-3m)=0$$ for $t=1$. That yields $m=\frac{11}{18}$.
We must now check whether the tangent line lies on the desired side of the graph of $\frac{2t^2}{t^2-t+6}$. We want to have $$\frac{2t^2}{t^2-t+6}\ge\frac{1}{3}+\frac{11}{18}(t-1)$$ and that boils down to $$(t-1)^2(30-11t)\ge 0$$ which is obvious for $2>t>0$.
